# How can i do a simple switch of characters from using indexes

Tags: javascript

Greetings I am trying to do a simple swap by comparing 2 numbers from a string and the switching the higher number to the left. I am using a while loop to make the changes but i get a ***TypeError: input is not a function chartest.html:32:4***
I do not see what i am doing wrong can anyone look at my code. Here is a look at my code.

```
<body>
<form>
   Enter numbers to be sorted from into high to low
   <input id="num" type="text" value="" >    
<br>output<input id="forTest" type="text">
<br><button type="button" onclick="calc(); return false" >Enter</button>
<input type="reset">
</form>

<p id="what"></p>

<script>
function calc() 
{   
var input = document.getElementById("num").value; 
var wordlength = input.length; 
var i = 0;

while(i < wordlength -1)
{
    a = input.charAt(i);
    b = input.charAt(i+1);
    if(a < b)
    {
        input(i) = b;
        input(i+1) =a; 

    }
    i++;
}

alert(input);

//document.getElementById("forTest").value = testString;
//document.getElementById("what").innerHTML = testString;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `input[i] = b;` instead of `input(i) = b;`. Using () means invoke. Using [] means character at index.

Comment: replace the contents of function calc() with one line ... `alert(document.getElementById("num").value.split('').sort().reverse().join(''));` - you're welcome

Comment: The thing im trying to do is create the algorithm by hand but I cant get around why I cant manipulate the array with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming is your friend :)

```
var input = document.getElementById("num").value; 
var arrayOfChars=input.split(""); //Or split by comma or whatever
var sortedArrayOfChars=arrayOfChars.sort(sortingFunction);

function sortingFunction(a,b){return a-b;}
```

Or, as a 1 liner...

```
input.split("").sort(function(a,b){return a-b;})
```